# Can I disable scrolling an an ASP.net page?

Tags: asp.net, scroll

I have an html banner at the top of an .aspx page and a silverlight app sitting below it. I want the app to be a one-page experience and not allow any scrolling. The problem is that the different browsers have different amounts of screen area so that in Firefox the banner+app may fit on the page without scroll bars, but then the same page in IE9 will have scroll bars because there isn't enough screen area to display both on screen. My app is designed with a large footer at the bottom to account for this, but I need the footer to go below the bottom of the screen without giving the user the option to scroll down to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in css write:

```
body{overflow:hidden; position:relative}
```

Comment: 'position:relative' will make it run in ie6 browser too.

Comment: When I do that it just puts the entire app on screen and no longer respects the margin-top:100px

Comment: Actually this technique works properly in firefox but not in IE.

Comment: where you have given margin, in body or in a div inside body.

Comment: so basically in IE I see the banner for a split second and then the app get's pushed back up to the top and covers the banner. I'm guessing it allows the margin and then once it notices scrolling is disables it goes back and undoes it... kind of weird right, and ideas?

Comment: margin is in a div inside the body.

Comment: but I don't want to set the margin for everything on the page, just for the silverlight app.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `overflow` property](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) in CSS:

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2zV3k/).